# Stripe Payment Success URL Redirect With Parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm working with the following Stripe.js file in a Next.js project:

```
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

export async function Stripe({ lineItems }, imageUrls) {
  let stripePromise = null;

  const getStripe = () => {
    if (!stripePromise) {
      stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY);
    }
    return stripePromise;
  };

  const stripe = await getStripe();

  await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    mode: "payment",
    lineItems,
    successUrl: `http://localhost:3000/success?pdf=${imageUrls}`,
    cancelUrl: window.location.origin,
  });
}
```

When I call the Stripe function, I'm passing an imageUrls array which looks like this for example:

```
['blob:http://localhost:3000/2a47a926-be04-49a9-ad96-3279c540ebb4']
```

When the Stripe redirectToCheckout happens, I navigate to the success page and pass imageUrls.

My goal is to convert these imageUrls into png images from the success page using code like this inside of an async function:

```
const fileResponse = await fetch(imageUrl);
const contentType = fileResponse.headers.get("content-type");
const blob = await fileResponse.blob();
const imageFile = new File([blob], `someImage.png`, {
contentType,
});
```

I end up getting this error though:

```
GET blob:http://localhost:3000/2a47a926-be04-49a9-ad96-3279c540ebb4 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I'm guessing after the redirect this URL doesn't exist anymore? What is the correct way to make something like this work?

Edit to include success.js code:

```
import Layout from "../components/Layout/Layout";
import { useEffect } from "react";

function SuccessPage() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const params = new Proxy(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search), {
      get: (searchParams, prop) => searchParams.get(prop),
    });
    let value = params.pdf;
    console.log("this is value");
    console.log(value);

    async function getFileFromUrl(imageUrl) {
      const fileResponse = await fetch(imageUrl);
      const contentType = fileResponse.headers.get("content-type");
      const blob = await fileResponse.blob();
      const ditheredImageFile = new File([blob], `test.png`, {
        contentType,
      });
      return ditheredImageFile;
    }
    let imageFile = getFileFromUrl(value);
    console.log("this is imageFile");
    console.log(imageFile);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <h3>Thank You For Your Order!</h3>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default SuccessPage;
```

[image]

Comment: `http://localhost:3000/2a47a926-be04-49a9-ad96-3279c540ebb4` is a valid url? Your image should either be in the public folder, OR if it's an image return by api it should be `/api/image/2a47a926-be04-49a9-ad96-3279c540ebb4` where `/api/image/` is the image api. So I guess you need to first get that part right.

Comment: It seems to be a valid URL before the redirect. That is to say, I'm able to work with the URL and convert it into a .png image before I do the Stripe redirect. After the redirect, the URL must be invalid though. Any guidance on why that is?

Comment: And I'm able to see the image in the browser when I hit the URL http://localhost:3000/2a47a926-be04-49a9-ad96-3279c540ebb4 before the redirect.

Comment: first and foremost, did u follow the answer below to remove the "blob"from url?

Comment: There probably need more info, or if you can a demo repo that we can run on our end, for your bounty to get any response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using blobs and you shouldn't - and I'm guessing those blobs came from a user input.

Blobs in javascript work in-memory (RAM), they will be discarded when your document unloads.

Since you're redirect the user to another page (stripe) you're unloading your document and thus loosing everything you've in memory (all your blobs are gone, they are only good while your document is loaded, after you leave it/get redirected they are cleared from memory).

To solve your problem you must simply upload the documents to a server prior to unloading the document (redirecting the user to stripe) and pass your server URL instead of your "internal" (blob) URL and all should work.

Basically, you need to save your files on a server via AJAX, have the server save the files and return their URL's (or even better, an ID for your image collection) and use those server URL's on the redirect (or an ID that you'll use to retrieve all the files you need later, simplifying your parameter usage).

More info at: https://javascript.info/blob ("Blob as URL" section)

Answer (score 3):

The localhost url will not work because Stripe has no way of accessing an image on your local machine. **Instead, you should upload the image to a database and provide a public URL.** I'm not sure what systems (e.g. AWS, Azure) you use, so it's hard to get very specific.

The database can then be queried after landing on the checkout page. One way to do this would be to pass the ID of the item as a URL param. Another way is to store information about the product in local storage.

Either way, you should get a response from your database with a unique link or ID so you know exactly what to query later.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the image data as a base64 encoded string to the success URL and then decode it in the success page to get the actual image data.

modify your code:

On the Stripe function:

```
const imageUrls = lineItems.map((item) => {
  return btoa(item.url);
});

// ...

successUrl: `http://localhost:3000/success?pdf=${imageUrls}`,

// ...
```

On the SuccessPage

```
async function getFileFromUrl(imageUrl) {
  const decodedUrl = atob(imageUrl);
  const fileResponse = await fetch(decodedUrl);
  const contentType = fileResponse.headers.get("content-type");
  const blob = await fileResponse.blob();
  const ditheredImageFile = new File([blob], `test.png`, {
    contentType,
  });
  return ditheredImageFile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think error is coming from this one
**blob url will be only available in the same origin context, but your successurl is not the same as like blob**

please try to generate dataurls from blob.

```
const dataUrls = await Promise.all(
    imageUrls.map(async (url) => {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const blob = await response.blob();
      return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    })
  );

  await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    mode: "payment",
    lineItems,
    successUrl: `http://localhost:3000/success?pdf=${encodeURIComponent(dataUrls.join(","))}`,
    cancelUrl: window.location.origin,
  });
```

And then please decode urls at the success page, then you could resolve your issues.